# File Directory Not Found (But File Exists)

Tags: lua

I have made a lua script where I am trying to open up a file directory but it keeps telling me there are none (I do have the file inside the folder with the current script)

[image: 1]

The following is the script,

```
local Thread = assert(io.open("script.lua", "r"))
local scriptContent = Thread:read("*all")
Thread:close()
```

Comment: set the flags which code editor you are using and determine the current directory

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this, instead of trying to run it in the terminal (for visual studio) I simply opened up cmd and ran it through there. If you don't know how to run it in cmd, I'll list it under.

1. Go to the file directory (of the Lua script) and type `cmd` up at the top of the editable directory path.
2. Then type `lua foldername.lua` (of course, replace `foldername` with the folder name).